# VBA Bestfit position for datalabels on line chart

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to make my own function to reposition data labels on line chart so they'll be in their best fit.

What does it mean best fit?

The data label wont be above the line itself (I took the higher angle of the point and put the data label in higher-angle/2 - so it will be in the middle of the higher angle) - I succeed to get the higher-angle but didn't succeed to get the position on graph (in pixels, relatively)

After u put the data label in the middle of the higher angle, you need to check with the other `seriescollections`, that the data label is not above one of other `seriescollections` line... - didn't reach this part.

and still I am not sure that's it...

Is anybody got something prepared? or someone wants to help me with it?

It is way over my level right now...

Comment: Once you have something that works for Excel 2007..it probably won't work for Excel 2010 or 2003. MS consistently change the charting framework for Excel so most dump the data into a more reliable app these days.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Jon Peltier's](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ChartIndex.html) site? There's a ton of examples for how to manipulate charts; some examples involve data labels.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett, Yes. I checked Jon Peltier's site. he has nothing related to what I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some tries, I decided to ditch the idea since this's way too complicated for me.

What I can say is that I ditch it after I stepped up a little bit.
I could find the best position for each label only when there's one line.

I achieved it by calculating the bigger arc (assumed each point is the middle of a circle), and than put it in the middle of that arc.

to do it when you have more than one line, you have to consider the position of the points of the other line/s. Therefore it becomes much more complicated and this is the reason I decided to ditch it.

Answer (score 1):

"Best fit" is a setting unique to pie chart data labels.

You have the option of positioning a line chart's data labels centered (directly on a point), as well as above, below, left of, and right of the point. You can also position the data label anywhere by changing the .left and .top properties of the label. Left and Top are in points with respect to the top left corner of the chart, so you will have to brush up on your algebra to fine tune label positioning.

As with all else involving charts, Keep It Simple is sound advice. Do you need to label everything, or can you get away with a few key labels?